# SQL Server UPDATE Command Fails without error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

Using SSMS running the below UPDATE command I get returned message says 1 row affected. but if I then follow it up with a Select and it shows that the row never updated.

This issue happens in SSMS and a custom application I built in C# using Entity Framework. I have since stopped using Entity Framework generated code and moved straight to a stored procedure. All of 3 different ways of performing the same task I randomly get this issue. Sometimes it can be 100's or 1000's of updates before the issue happens again or it could be a few updates later it happens again.

I have run `UPDATE STATISTICS`, I have rebuilt indexes and reorganized indexes.

As a side note, I NEVER have an issue with INSERTs only UPDATEs we never DELETE any records. and total record count on the table is 201,741

```
UPDATE CreativeWorkFlowQueue
SET CurrentIndicator = 'N'
WHERE CreativeWorkFlowQueueId = 198231

SELECT *
FROM CreativeWorkFlowQueue
WHERE CreativeWorkFlowQueueId = 198231
```

[image]

Here is the table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CreativeWorkFlowQueue]
(
    [CreativeWorkFlowQueueId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DigitalCampaignCreativeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WorkFlowQueueId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CurrentIndicator] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CreativeWorkFlowQueueId] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CreativeWorkFlowQueue] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [CreateDate defaults to utcDate on CreativeWorkFlowQueue]   
        DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE()) FOR [CreateDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CreativeWorkFlowQueue] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [LastUpdatedDate defaults to utcDate on CreativeWorkFlowQueue]  
        DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE()) FOR [LastUpdatedDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CreativeWorkFlowQueue] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_CreativeWorkFlowQueue_IsDeleted]  
        DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsDeleted]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CreativeWorkFlowQueue] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [CreativeWorkFlowQueue DigitalCampaignCreativeId fk] 
        FOREIGN KEY([DigitalCampaignCreativeId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[DigitalCampaignCreative] ([DigitalCampaignCreativeId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CreativeWorkFlowQueue] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CreativeWorkFlowQueue DigitalCampaignCreativeId fk]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CreativeWorkFlowQueue] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [CreativeWorkFlowQueue WorkFlowQueueId fk] 
        FOREIGN KEY([WorkFlowQueueId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[WorkFlowQueue] ([WorkFlowQueueId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CreativeWorkFlowQueue] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CreativeWorkFlowQueue WorkFlowQueueId fk]
GO
```

**EDIT** adding the stored procedure that also has the same issue:

I did not include this stored procedure simply due to the fact that it is complex and if a simple update doesn't work I figured start there first.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_WtvToRtl] 
    @tbl DCCIdList READONLY,    
    @WorkFlowQueueId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    DECLARE @dccList TABLE (
        CreativeWorkflowQueueId int null,
        DigitalCampaignCreativeId int null,
        WorkFlowQueueId int null,
        CurrentIndicator varchar(1) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS null,
        LastUpdatedDate datetime null
    )

    DECLARE @DCIDList TABLE(
        DigitalCampaignCreativeId int null
    )





        DECLARE @res TABLE (
        MergeAction VARCHAR(50) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
        CreativeWorkFlowQueueId INT, 
        _Position INT
        )

    BEGIN TRANSACTION t1

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO @dccList (CreativeWorkflowQueueId, DigitalCampaignCreativeId,LastUpdatedDate,WorkFlowQueueId,CurrentIndicator)
        select CreativeWorkflowQueueId, DigitalCampaignCreativeId,LastUpdatedDate,WorkFlowQueueId, 'N' as CurrentIndicator from 
        dbo.CreativeWorkFlowQueue Where CurrentIndicator = 'Y' 
        and IsDeleted = 0
        and DigitalCampaignCreativeId In 
        (SELECT DigitalCampaignCreativeId FROM VRF.DigitalCampaignCreative 
        WHERE IsDeleted = 0 and SfClosed = 0 
        and DccId in (Select DccId COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS from @tbl)
        )
         
         INSERT INTO @DCIDList 
         SELECT DigitalCampaignCreativeId FROM @dccList
         GROUP BY DigitalCampaignCreativeId

        INSERT INTO @dccList (DigitalCampaignCreativeId,WorkFlowQueueId,CurrentIndicator)
        select DigitalCampaignCreativeId, @WorkFlowQueueId as WorkFlowQueueId, 'Y' as CurrentIndicator from 
        @DCIDList


        MERGE vrf.CreativeWorkFlowQueue a
        USING 
            (
            SELECT 
                x.CreativeWorkflowQueueId,
                x.DigitalCampaignCreativeId,
                x.LastUpdatedDate,
                x.WorkFlowQueueId,
                x.CurrentIndicator 
            FROM @dccList x
            ) stg  
    
        ON stg.CreativeWorkflowQueueId = a.CreativeWorkflowQueueId

        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET 
                a.CurrentIndicator  = stg.CurrentIndicator,
                a.LastUpdatedDate = getutcdate()
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT 
                (
                    CurrentIndicator,
                    DigitalCampaignCreativeId,
                    WorkFlowQueueId
                )
            VALUES 
                (
                    stg.CurrentIndicator, 
                    stg.DigitalCampaignCreativeId, 
                    stg.WorkFlowQueueId
                )  
            -- ********************************************************************
            -- Remove this if you don't need to return the results below.
            OUTPUT 
                INSERTED.CreativeWorkFlowQueueId,
                $action 
            INTO @res (CreativeWorkFlowQueueId, MergeAction);
            -- ********************************************************************


        COMMIT TRANSACTION t1

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX), @ErrorSeverity INT, @ErrorState INT;
        SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' Line ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS NVARCHAR(5)), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION t1
        --RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
        SELECT 'FAILED' MergeAction,
                s.CreativeWorkflowQueueId,
                s.DigitalCampaignCreativeId,
                '' DccId,
                s.WorkFlowQueueId,
                s.CurrentIndicator,
                null CreateDate,
                null LastUpdatedDate,
                null IsDeleted,
                @ErrorMessage ErrorMessage
        FROM @dccList s
    END CATCH


    -- Normally, I would not have this.  But this will simulate
    -- what EF does if you need it.
    SELECT 
        r.MergeAction,
        a.CreativeWorkFlowQueueId,
        a.DigitalCampaignCreativeId,
        d.DccId,
        a.WorkFlowQueueId,
        a.CurrentIndicator,
        a.CreateDate, 
        a.LastUpdatedDate,
        a.IsDeleted,
        '' ErrorMessage
    FROM vrf.CreativeWorkFlowQueue a 
    JOIN @res r ON a.CreativeWorkFlowQueueId = r.CreativeWorkFlowQueueId
    JOIN vrf.DigitalCampaignCreative d ON a.DigitalCampaignCreativeId = d.DigitalCampaignCreativeId
    ORDER BY 
        r.MergeAction,
        r._Position


END
```

The user-defined table type is this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DCCIdList] AS TABLE(
    [DccId] [nvarchar](18) NULL
)
```

Comment: Not that it should impact the problem, but the "LastUpdatedDate" column doesn't update itself. You should update it as part of the Update statement. That *might* shed some light.

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the table?

Comment: Given the nature of this issue (its not really programming) you might get more traction on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can add an [`output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause to the `update` to get the _before_ and _after_ values. Without a transaction there could be another process updating the data between the `update` and `select` statements.

Comment: Do you have multiple databases (in the same server instance or different instances) with this same table?

Comment: @BlackLight yeah I hear you on that, I included the Stored Proc that I use normally which does update the lastupdateddate, also the results from the SP does show that the action performed was UPDATE for the records in question but obviously it did not work.

Comment: I would suggest you refactor your update to simply `update` and then `insert` if no rows updated - ie - do away with `merge` and see if you still encounter an issue. [bugs with merge](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). You should also always check `@@trancount` in the catch when rolling back.

Comment: Yeah I could see how I could incorporate that but that seems more of putting a bandaid on a gashing wound.

Comment: maybe your transactions have become out of sync? Try checking @@trancount at various places to make sure it is what you expect. I'd also suggest using SET XACT_ABORT ON if possible - see: https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html

Comment: `CreativeWorkFlowQueue` sounds like it could be a queue. i.e.: Is there another process polling that table to do something and then resets `CurrentIndicator` to `Y` when done?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: As suggested, I would add an " output inserted.* " clause to the simple update statement. I think you'll find that SQL Update statements work. I would be looking to find what else is updating your record (ie. a process on a different thread) - as this would fit the "mostly it works, sometimes not".

Comment: @BlackLight yeah I thought the same thing about something else possibly updating it back to "Y" but two things about that, If that was happening the "LastUpdatedDate" would have been updated too since all of my code updates the LastUpdatedDate along with the CurrentIndicator. Plus I went through my code to ensure there was no where that would be assigning this value back.

Comment: What happens if you run the command as: 

UPDATE dbo.CreativeWorkFlowQueue
SET CurrentIndicator = 'N'
WHERE CreativeWorkFlowQueueId = 198231
in the corresponding database?

Comment: That has the same issue, sometimes. I wasn't going to include the full Stored Proc and was going to leave it as just that UPDATE command to show how even a simple straight forward query experiences the same issue.